# SSIS: Data integration between SQL server 2008 R2 To PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SSIS package where I take data from SQL Server Table, data conversion  and load that into a table in PostgreSQL.

**Package details**:

Source : OLEDB Source

Transformation : Data Conversion (varchar data type conversion)

Destination : ADO NET Destination

Database connected is successfully using ADO.Net

Mapping has been done properly between Data conversion to Destination.

While executing package getting following error:

> [ADO NET Destination [192]] Error: ADO NET Destination has failed to
>   acquire the connection {B63BB8E1-515E-4687-89D9-990575FBD5F0}. The
>   connection may have been corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to do some settings to overcome with this problem.

**Settings**:

Setting properties of data flow task:

Go to Properties -> Execution

> DelayValidation = True

Setting properties of control flow task:

Go to Properties -> Execution

> DelayValidation = True

Setting properties of Solution:

Go to Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Debug Options

> Run64BitRuntime = False